# Is there a long-term risk to sleeping in a hammock regularly?

Tags: sleep, research, spine

There seems to be very little research on long-term health or spine drawbacks to sleeping in a hammock (anything besides individuals informal blog-type posts).
Just one study about sleeping in a hammock would be valuable.

- Some claim the spine decompresses in a hammock.
- Some claim that a hammock does not provide the body support it needs.

[image: Living in a van]

Comment: *"Some claim the spine decompresses in a hammock.

Some claim that a hammock does not provide the body support it needs"* Can you cite these claims?

Comment: No, I cannot. They are from memory.